# What's the difference between result_of<F(Args...> and decltype<f(args...)>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I see that `std::async` is specified as follows:

```
template <class F, class... Args>                   // copied out of the standard
future<typename result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
async(F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

I had expected it to be declared like this:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
auto async(F&& f, Args&&... args) ->
  future<decltype(forward<F>(f)(forward<Args>(args)...)>;
```

Would that be equivalent, or is there some way in which the use of `result_of` is preferable to the use of `decltype`? (I understand that `result_of` works with types, while `decltype` works with expressions.)

Comment: Is it _specified_ or _implemented_ with `result_of`? Because that could just be a whim of the guy who implemented it, or it could have been implemented before `decltype` made it to the target compiler. In Apple's libc++, it uses neither.

Comment: @zneak: The declaration I showed is copied out of the standard, so `std::async` is specified via `result_of`. Implementations can do whatever they like, as long as the behavior they provide is the same as what's specified.

Comment: Just know that there are some [unfortunate implications with the `std::result_of` syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15489789/500104).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your version doesn't work with e.g. pointers to members. A closer, but still not exact version would be:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
auto async(F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> future<decltype( ref(f)(forward<Args>(args)...) )>;
```

The only difference remaining with `std::result_of` is that this forwards the functor as an lvalue (a problem your version also shares). In other words, the result of such a call (via an `std::reference_wrapper<F>`) is `typename std::result_of<F&(Args...)>::type`.

This is an awkward situation where several components of the Standard library (to name a few, in addition to those we've just witnessed: `std::thread`, `std::bind`, `std::function`) are specified in terms of an elusive *INVOKE(f, a0, a1, ..., aN)* pseudo-expression, which isn't exactly equivalent to `f(a0, a1, ... aN)`. Since `std::result_of` is one of those components, and serves in fact to compute the result type of *INVOKE*, that's the discrepancy you're noticing.

Because there is no `std::invoke` that comes in tandem with the `std::result_of` type trait I am of the opinion that the latter is only useful for describing e.g. the return types of the relevant Standard Library components, when your code calls them. If you want a concise and self-documenting way of writing e.g. a return type (a very worthy goal for readability, compared to sprinkling `decltype` everywhere), then I recommend you write your own alias:

```
template<typename F, typename... A>
using ResultOf = decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<A>()...) );
```

(If you want the alias to be used as `ResultOf<F(A...)>` instead of `ResultOf<F, A...>` then you need a little bit of machinery to pattern match over the function signature.)

An added benefit of this alias is that it is SFINAE friendly, unlike `std::result_of`. Yes, that is one more of its flaws. (To be fair though this has been amended for the upcoming Standard and implementations are following suit already.)

You would not be missing anything if you were using such a trait because you can adapt pointers to members thanks to `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: I modified the original code so that the `decltype` version applies `std::forward` to `f`, thus presumably eliminating the problem that all function objects were treated at lvalues. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, because I think the observation that the `decltype` version wouldn't support pointers to members is important.

Answer (score 5):

No difference at all from functional point of view. However, the `decltype` version uses *trailing-return-type*, that is one difference from programming point of view.

In C++11, the `std::result_of` is not absolutely necessary, one can use `decltype` instead, like the way you've used. But `std::result_of` is backward-compatible with third party libraries (older ones) such as Boost which has `result_of`. I don't see much advantage, though.

Personally, I prefer to use `decltype` as it is more powerful and works with *any* entities, whereas `result_of` works with callable entities only. So if I use `decltype`, I can use it everywhere. But with `result_of`, I've to occasionally switch to `decltype` (that is, when the entity is *not* callable). See [this at github](https://github.com/snawaz/foam/blob/master/composition/operator.h) where I've used `decltype` in return type of all functions.

Comment: Another programming difference is that the `decltype` version requires the use of `forward`, whereas the `return_of` version apparently does not.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: As you've noticed yourself (in the question), `std::result_of` works with *types*, so there is nothing to forward.

Comment: I think you mean `std::result_of` where you wrote `std::result_type`.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Yes. corrected long back. Refresh your page. And see my edited answer as well.

Comment: I'm referring to the `std::result_type` in the second paragraph. But now I'm thinking maybe you want it there, because you're talking about backwards compatibility.

Comment: @zneak: it is `std::result_of`, not `std::result_type`. please don't edit the answer again!

Comment: @Nawaz, it was `result_type` at first, and I changed it to `result_of`. Seeing @KnowItAllWannabe's comment, I reverted it because I didn't want to have to check or be proven wrong. (You can see it in your post's history, rev 5-6.)

Comment: @zneak: Oh. I saw that now. Anyway, it should be `std::result_of`. `result_type` was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

You already had the difference in your questions: "I understand that `result_of` works with types, while `decltype` works with expressions."

They both provide the same functionality (`std::result_of` is even implemented in terms of `decltype` nowadays) and the difference for *your example* is mostly non-existent, because you already have the necessary variables to build an expression.

That said, the difference boils down to syntactic sugar for when you only have the types. Consider:

```
typename std::result_of< F( A, B, C ) >::type
```

vs.

```
decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<A>(), std::declval<B>(), std::declval<C>() )
```

And just remember that `std::result_of` is an option in those cases.

Note that there are also cases where `decltype` can be used in a way that `std::result_of` can't. Consider `decltype( a + b )`, you can not find an `F` to create an equivalent `std::result_of< F( A, B ) >` as far as I know.

Comment: Do you really want to use `std::declval` on each of the template arguments instead of `std::forward`?

Comment: It's for the case when you only have the **type** available, please read the answer again. Without a variable of said type, you can not use `std::forward` as it needs a parameter.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that you were using only types.