# the weird result_of<F(Ts...)> in Andrei Alexandrescu's talk about exploding tuple

Tags: c++11, tuples

Has anyone watched Andrei Alexandrescu's talk about exploding tuple in GoingNative2013 yet?

Here is the piece of code I don't quite follow:

```
template <class F, class... Ts>
auto explode(F&& f, const tuple<Ts...>& t)
    -> typename result_of<F(Ts...)>::type
{
    return Expander<sizeof...(Ts),
       typename result_of<F(Ts...)>::type,
       F,
       const tuple<Ts...>&>::expand(f, t);
}
```

the F(Ts...) in result_of trouble me much. I mean: doesn't F stands for a function type ?
I know R(Ts...) well, but the R here is a return type, but using F in place where R should be, that's the thing driving me crazy...

Can anyone help me understand the weird F(Ts...) here ?

Here is the link forward to Andrei Alexandrescu's talk:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/The-Way-of-the-Exploding-Tuple

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486951/why-does-stdresult-of-take-an-unrelated-function-type-as-a-type-argument) for more info about `result_of` and its admittedly funky syntax.

Comment: FYI: Stephan T. Lavavej explained in the last five minutes of his talk about [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) how `explode` is implemented correctly.

Comment: `result_of<F(Ts...)>::types` means the return type of calling an object of type `F` with arguments of type `Ts`. If you understand `decltype` then it is similar to `decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Ts>()...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The question you want to ask is probably a duplicate of this one: [Why does std::result_of take an (unrelated) function type as a type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486951/why-does-stdresult-of-take-an-unrelated-function-type-as-a-type-argument)

Let's dissect:

```
std::result_of<F(Ts...)>::type
```

So, somewhere in `namespace std`, we've got a class template `result_of<>`. It takes one template type parameter; i.e., it looks basically like this:

```
template<typename Foo>
struct result_of
{
    typedef FOOBARBAZ type;
};
```

Okay, so, we're instantiating this template with the parameter `F(Ts...)`. That's unusual syntax! You presumably know that `Ts` is a parameter pack, and therefore the `Ts...` inside the parentheses will expand at compile time to a comma-separated list of types, for example `int, double, bool`. So we've got `F(int, double, bool)`. Okay, that's a function type.

Just as `int(char)` means "function taking `char` and returning `int`", so does `F(int, double, bool)` mean "function taking `int, double, bool` and returning `F`".

"But wait," you say. "I thought `F` was already my function type!"

Yes. `F` is ***your*** function type. But the type expected by `std::result_of` is, *really!,* that function type wrapped up in *another* function type. To elaborate:

```
typedef int (*F)(char);
typedef F G(char);
static_assert(std::is_same< std::result_of<G>::type, int >::value);
static_assert(std::is_same< std::result_of<F(char)>::type, int >::value);
static_assert(std::is_same< std::result_of<int (*(char))(char)>::type, int >::value);
```

Each of the above lines is exactly equivalent: `F(char)` is just a much more aesthetically pleasing way of writing `int (*(char))(char)`. Of course, you can't always get away with it, because sometimes `F` is a function type that can't be returned from a function:

```
typedef int F(char);
std::result_of<F(char)>;  // fails to compile
```

As @Simple wrote in the comments, `std::result_of<F(Ts...)>::type` can always be replaced with the less clever but also less confusing expression

```
decltype( std::declval<F>() ( std::declval<Ts>()... ) )
```

i.e., "the `decltype` of the result of calling a value of type `F` with arguments of types `Ts...`. Here, there are no wacky higher-level function types; everything just works the way you'd naturally expect it to. Personally, I would probably use the `decltype` approach in my own code, just because it's easier to understand; but I imagine that some people would prefer the `std::result_of` approach because it looks superficially simpler and is blessed by the Standard. To each his own. :)